# Java & Mongodb -- how to update where not in array

Tags: java, mongodb

this array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

```
    {
       "number" : 11,
       ...
    },
    {
       "number" : 9,
       ...
    },
    {     
       "number" : 3,
       ...
    },
    {    
       "number" : 20,
       ...
    },
    {     
       "number" : 5,
       ...
    },
    {    
       "number" : 7,
       ...
    }
```

I want to update number : 11 20

I did not find documentation on this.

Answer (score -1):

I think I know what this question is supposed to ask. It seems like I've misinterpreted it "earlier".

You have an array stored in `mongodb` like that:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "test" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ] }
```

You have another array somewhere within your program:

```
[11, 9, 3, 20, 5, 7]
```

And you want to update the array stored in `mongodb` adding only values that do not exist there yet(uniquely).

If that is the question here is the answer:

---

How to do do that in the console:

```
db.yourdb.updateOne({ _id: ObjectId("...")}, {$addToSet: {"test": {$each: [20, 11]}}})
```

[`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) ensures that it is added only once and [`$each`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#addtoset-modifiers) will prevent that an array is added instead like that: `[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, [20, 11]]`.

In Java:

I'm not familiar with the Java driver, but it should go something like this:

```
coll.updateOne(Filters.eq("_id", "..."), new Document("$addToSet", new Document("test", new Document("$each", [11, 9, 3, 20, 5, 7]))));
```